# How to replace the command zhnumber with the equivalent command which add numbers in English in latex

Tags: latex

I have a template of thesis which has two table of contents, the first one is written in Chinese and the second one in English. After I reversed them, it means I made the Chinese table of content be English and the second one Chinese, the numbers are still same, I couldn't change them.

After checking the code of the templated, I found this line:

```
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]
{\markboth{}{Chapter \zhnumber{\thechapter} \hspace{2ex} #1}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]
{\markright{\thesection\quad #1}}
```

where the `zhnumber` provide the numbers in Chinese, so I was wondering, how can I replace that command to make it providing the numbers in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `zhnumber` command: this provides the English (actually, Arabic) numbers:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]
{\markboth{}{Chapter {\thechapter} \hspace{2ex} #1}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]
{\markright{\thesection\quad #1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the numbers in the chapters itself are still shown in Chinese !! That answer modified that numbers only in the content. How can I modify the numbers in the chapter itself also?

Comment: @Sajjad I get all the numbers in Arabic: have you tried to clean all the auxiliary files and then recompile again?